# Contar y sumar registros de 2 tablas sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tardes me pueden ayudar para ver como puedo unir estas 2 consultas, en una de ellas me suma la cantidad de registros con un case when y en la otra consulta me cuenta las piezas registradas por su numero de lote y numero de parte.

```
(Select DISTINCT lt.confnumero As 'LINE', lt.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', SUBSTRING(lt.lotenumero, 2, 8) As 'NO.LOTE', CASE WHEN lt.nparnumero + lt.lotenumero = lt.nparnumero + lt.lotenumero THEN SUM(lt.lotecantidad) end as 'QTY.LOTES' FROM Lotes lt where lt.lotefentrega = '2022-06-24' GROUP BY lt.nparnumero, lt.confnumero, lt.lotenumero)
UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT dp.confnumero as 'LINE', dp.detnumpart as 'PART.NUMBER', dp.lotenumero as 'NO.LOTE', COUNT(dp.pdetetiq) as 'QTY.PROD' from Detalle_Piezas dp WHERE dp.pdetfecha LIKE '2022-06-24' GROUP BY dp.confnumero, dp.detnumpart, dp.lotenumero)
```

Se puede unir en una sola consulta?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa `JOIN`:

```sql
select a.*, b.*
from 
(Select DISTINCT lt.confnumero As 'LINE', lt.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', 
SUBSTRING(lt.lotenumero, 2, 8) As 'NO.LOTE', 
CASE WHEN lt.nparnumero + lt.lotenumero = lt.nparnumero + lt.lotenumero 
     THEN SUM(lt.lotecantidad) end as 'QTY.LOTES' 
FROM Lotes lt where lt.lotefentrega = '2022-06-24' 
GROUP BY lt.nparnumero, lt.confnumero, lt.lotenumero) a

join 

(SELECT DISTINCT dp.confnumero as 'LINE', dp.detnumpart as 'PART.NUMBER', 
dp.lotenumero as 'NO.LOTE', COUNT(dp.pdetetiq) as 'QTY.PROD' 
from Detalle_Piezas dp 
WHERE dp.pdetfecha LIKE '2022-06-24' 
GROUP BY dp.confnumero, dp.detnumpart, dp.lotenumero) b 

ON

a.LINE = b.LINE
```

Comment: Buenas tardes me marca error de syntax near 'b'

Comment: ah claro, perdón! falta que los unas con `ON`, ahí lo edité.

Comment: @isanchezo, no aun me marca ahora las columnas invalidas [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'confnumero'. (207)
  [42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'confnumero'. (207)

Comment: tienes que colocarle el alias, lo volví a editar jaja

Comment: Muchas gracias y  a esta consulta no se puede unificar para que al lado del se la suma o la cantidad muestre solo como columna adicional? En vez de unir sea fucionar las dos en una sola con 6 columnas, lina,numero de parte, no lote, qty lotes y agregra la columna qty prod?

Comment: Se debería de poder con un `GROUP BY`, pero tienes que pasarme un ejemplo demostrable (SQLFiddle o DBFiddle) porque así solo lo estoy imaginando y seguramente te daría una respuesta errada.

Comment: Ok y eso como seria soy nuevo en este detalle. muchas gracias